# How to make the alarm that sound at phone shutdown time in Android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I had made a reminder that I want it to sound when the phone at shutdown time.
I just konw that I set the `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP` when I execute`AlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent)`,but I had make a experiment , it not work.
Anyone solve it? Thank you!

Comment: What does alarmmanager have to do with the phone shutting down?

Comment: when the time out , the `BroadcastReceiver`  while get it ,then  sound

Comment: OK it must use ` AlarmManager.POWER_OFF_WAKEUP ` , but  I can' t find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tim Castelijns points out in the comments on the question, `AlarmManager` has nothing to do with the device shutting down.

You are certainly welcome to have a `BroadcastRecevier` registered [for `ACTION_SHUTDOWN`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SHUTDOWN). Since the device is shutting down, you may or may not be able to actually play a sound or otherwise notify the user at this point in time, but you are welcome to try.

Comment: it must use ` AlarmManager.POWER_OFF_WAKEUP ` , but  it only can be  use in  some low-level SDK ,  it can't be used now

Comment: @SweetLollipop why are you so convinced you must use that? Why not Intent.ACTION_SHUTDOWN as is suggested here?